# How to make a wireless display still showing a program when laptop is locked

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, laptop, external-display, miracast

I have a windows 10 laptop that connected via the wireless display with Samsung smart tv. The tv is displaying an excel workbook. When I lock my laptop, the tv is obviously will also lock too. Is there any way to make the tv stay show the excel when I lock my laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that.
A lock will lock ALL screens.

The lock serves 2 purposes:
1) Locking the computer so nobody can mess with it when you are away.
2) Protecting privacy/sensitive data. No one can look at it without you knowledge.

1) is obviously not a concern as there is no keyboard/mouse attached to the 2nd screen, but point 2) still applies. And that is why the locking mechanism locks all displays.